# Excel Error #Value when executing VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I've build a simple function to collect some values from a string. Example string would be "abc(1.1);abc(1.2);bac(1.3)". The goal is to get values and sum them up in the end and return them as the result. Msgbox about "valor"(the total sum) works great and shows the correct value. But I get and #Value error on the cell when using this function. Can you help me understand why?

```
Function Organize(CellRef As String) As Double

Dim i As Integer
Dim lentotal As Long
Dim inicio As Long
Dim fim As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim valor As Double
Dim check As String
a = 1
x = CellRef
lentotal = Len(x)

i = Len(x) - Len(Replace(x, ";", ""))
Dim tech(1 To 100) As Double


Do While a <= i + 1
    inicio = InStr(x, "(")
    fim = InStr(x, ")")

    'MsgBox Replace((Mid(x, inicio + 1, fim - inicio - 1)), ".", ",")
    tech(a) = Replace((Mid(x, inicio + 1, fim - inicio - 1)), ".", ",")
    If Left(x, 4) = "ABC" Then
        valor = valor + tech(a)
    End If

    If a > i Then
        MsgBox valor
        Organize = valor
        End
    Else
        x = Right(x, Len(x) - fim - 1)
    End If

    a = a + 1
Loop


End Function
```

Comment: I think you need to change a few things, at least with this example: `If LCase(Left(x, 3)) = "abc" Then` since you comparing lower case string and only 3 characters, and remove the `End`.

Comment: Thanks @JvdV for replying. All that cycle is working fine because "MsgBox valor" is giving me the correct value(i've just worte ABC as an example). The "end" is to stop the cycle there.

Comment: `End` should probably be `Exit Function`.

Comment: Yes, `End` terminates the entire VBA thing. You almost never need to use it.

Comment: Exit function did it! Thanks

Comment: FWIW a UDF shouldn't pop any `MsgBox` either.

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon. It was just there to make sure the result was correct. Will not be part of the final code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Exit Function` instead of `End`.